# safari adds a space below the body

Tags: html, safari

look at this simple [HTML page](http://jsfiddle.net/bertuz/Zb3J8/) on jsfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Gymcentral</title>
</head>
<body style="border: 1px solid orange; margin:0; padding: 0;">
   <!-- here content that fills the page-->
</body>
</html>
```

if I run it on safari (outside jsfiddle), it adds me a space below the body. In other words, the colored border is not sticked with the bottom edge of the page. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: you can just add a `div` container in body tag `<body><div style='border: 1px solid orange; margin:0; padding: 0;'>filles content</div></body>

Comment: good one, but it doesn't work